# BST: Analyze Given a Reference find previous

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I was looking at the code for given a reference to a node on a BST find the predecessor.

```
public static TreeNode findPredecessor(TreeNode node) {
    if (node == null)
        return null;

    if (node.getLeft() != null)
        return findMaximum(node.getLeft());

    TreeNode parent = node.getParent();

    TreeNode y = parent;
    TreeNode x = node;
    while (y != null && x == y.getLeft())
    {
        x = y;
        y = y.getParent();
    }


    return y;
}
```

I was just wondering what this part of the code does.

```
TreeNode y = parent;
TreeNode x = node;
while (y != null && x == y.getLeft())
{
    x = y;
    y = y.getParent();
}

return y;
```

what exactly is happening in the middle of the while loop?

Thank you!

Comment: It would have been much clearer using `parent` and `node` rather than `x` and `y`  like so: `while (parent != null && node == parent.getLeft())  {
         node = parent;
         parent = parent.getParent();
     }
     return parent;`

Answer (score 0):

In finding the predecessor there are two cases.

1. If the node has a non-null left subtree, its predecessor would be the largest node in the left subtree.
2. If it does not have a left subtree, then find the first node that is a  *right child* if *its* parent (traversing upwards starting from the node of interest). Then, the parent node is the predecessor.

---

```
TreeNode y = parent; //parent is node.getParent(); i.,e parent of node.
TreeNode x = node; //assigns node to x
while (y != null && x == y.getLeft()) 
{
    x = y; //the parent becomes the current node 
    y = y.getParent(); //the parent is the parent of the parent
}

return y;
```

The while condition `(y != null && x == y.getLeft())` says to continue till

- parent is non-null and
- the current node is a *left child* of its parent. i.e, keep going till a node that is a *right child* of its parent is found.
- Return the parent node as the result.

Let's see this with an example

```
    40
 30    50
          60
        55
      54
    53
```

The in-order traversal gives

```
30 40 50 53 54 55 60
```

The predecessor of 55 - the largest node in its left subtree - 54

The predecessor of 53 - the node, when traversing upwards, that is a right child of its parent is 60 - its parent 50 is the result.